# Broadcast receiver in a service doesn't receive alarm signal

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-broadcast, android-alarms

Here is my problem, I have a service started on boot or on the launch of the application, this service start an alarm which download a file every x minutes.
The problem is that the broadcast receiver doesn't seems to receive anything.

here is the concerned code:

```
@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, ServiceCalendrier.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startAlarm();

        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }



    public void startAlarm() {
        manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval =5000;

        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //this toast is printed
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            getIcs(arg0);// download function
            Toast.makeText(arg0, "getICS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();// this one doesn't appear
        }

    };
```

Do I have to declare my service as a receiver in my AndroidManifest?

Comment: You're creating an instance of a generic `BroadcastReceiver` but you aren't registering it or specifying an `IntentFilter` - even if registered the OS wouldn't know what `receiver` is 'listening' for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually managed to make it work.

```
public void startAlarm() {
        manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval =5000;//7200000;
        IntentFilter myFilter = new IntentFilter("WhatEverYouWant");

        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent("WhatEverYouWant");
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
        registerReceiver(receiver, myFilter);

        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

The androidManifest :

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name="MyService">
            <receiver android:name="MyService">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="WhatEverYouWant" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
        </service>
    </application>
```

I still have some work to understand how it works and clean my code but thank you very much for your help

Comment: Android Studio highlights this as an error - <receiver> cannot be a sub-element of <service>, it must be a sub-element of <application>.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your service in manidest file like this

```
  <application>
</activity>
........
..........
</activity>
        <service android:name=".ServiceNameClass"></service>
    </application>
```

also u need to register your broadcast somethink like this

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getBaseContext()).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,new IntentFilter("my-event"));
```

Comment: Ok, so my service is well declared.

Comment: u need to register your broadcast in service as well like above declared